# Granting privileges to a user named "Grant"?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-grant

```
CREATE USER 'Grant'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'bestpasswordever';
```

How do I grant permissions to a user who is named "Grant"? It throws an error.

```
GRANT INSERT, DELETE
ON table
TO Grant@localhost;
```

Error: 'Grant' is not valid at this position. Expecting an identifier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use backticks when using reserved keywords or identifiers with otherwise illegal characters as identifiers

```sql
GRANT INSERT, DELETE
ON table
TO `Grant`@localhost;
```

Apostrophes or double quotes are fine, too as per [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html):

> Quote user names and host names as identifiers or as strings, using either backticks (`), single quotation marks ('), or double quotation marks ("). For string-quoting and identifier-quoting guidelines, see Section 9.1.1, “String Literals”, and Section 9.2, “Schema Object Names”.

...but I'm a purist and will always use backticks in MySQL, for identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

```
GRANT INSERT,DELETE
ON table
TO 'Grant'@'localhost';
```

See [Section 6.2.4 (Specifying Account Names)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html) in the documentation.

> Account name syntax is 'user_name'@'host_name'.